# How to auto apply drag and drop effect to dynamically added element?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I use jquery ui to apply a drag and drop effect on a serial of DIVs, for example:

```
<div class="draggable">...</div>
<div class="draggable">...</div>
<div class="draggable">...</div>
<div class="draggable"> this DIV was dynamically added, not draggable </div>
```

The problem is dynamically added DIVs won't have this effect applied, how can i apply this effect on new members too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the .live() function with .draggable() directly, but you can use .live() with the mouseover event and re-attach .draggable() on mouseover like this.

```
$('.draggable').live('mouseover',function(){
    $(this).draggable();
});
```

Comment: After a little looking, perhaps it would be better to check it the item is already draggable before making it draggable.
    
$('.draggable').live('mouseover',function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('ui-draggable')) { $(this).draggable(); }
    });

Comment: .live has been deprecated now. 

Its better to use .on:-

$(body).on('mouseover', '.draggable', function(){
  $(this).draggable();
})

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the jQuery [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/). I believe you could use it here. If not - just attach `.draggable()` when you create your element.

Answer (score 0):

You might also like to take a loot at the [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method introduced with jQuery 1.4 which is slightly better than live()

Here is an article comparing both approaches - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-the-difference-between-live-and-delegate/