# Add handler multiple times in jquery

Tags: jquery

How does jquery handle event assignment when it comes to assigning the same handler multiple times?  Let's say I have

```
<div class="draggable">Some Text</div>
```

Are there any side effects (performance or otherwise) from calling the following multiple times?

```
$('.draggable').draggable();
```

Comment: I think that would depend on the implementation of `draggable()` which is not an event handler.

Comment: Have you tried? I assume that depends on how `draggable()` is implemented, but sure it is a difference whether you have to call one event listener or hundred.

Comment: And it would depend on the implementation of the custom code. In fact there is no need to implement it in such a way that it calls `draggable()` multiple times on the same DOM element, apart from laziness.

Comment: Funny coincidence: Maybe you are interested in the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585211/jquery-ui-draggable-how-to-know-an-element-is-draggable-initialized (that just came up a few minutes after yours) to avoid multiple calls to `draggable()`.

Comment: @Felix I was actually refering to my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583883/   I added a comment to the answer with the the logic from your suggestion.

Comment: @AdmSteck: Hehe, the question you answered to was the same that asked the question I linked to in my previous comment :-D This is really weird and somehow recursive ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you bind a event like 'keydown' multiple times to an element, it will get attached to
a queue of event handlers.
So you can do the math, the more handlers are called, the slower it will perform.