# JQuery UI Draggable - How to know an element is draggable initialized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

My logic is

```
if( !this.draginited() ) // a drag-disabled element shouldn't get pass here, as it is inited
  this.draggable({...})
```

I searched a lot and couldn't find a way to implement this logic, any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe there's an easier way, but the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-stack) say:

> Draggable elements gets a class of
>   ui-draggable

so you could do something like:

```
if(!$("#foo").hasClass("ui-draggable")) {
    ...
}
```

so to wrap that up (untested):

```
$.fn.isDraggable = function() {
    return $(this).hasClass("ui-draggable");
}

console.log($("#someElement").isDraggable());
```

Answer (score 0):

The `dragstart` event is fired when dragging is started.  More in the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-start)